# Is zookeeper required for partitions on single machine?

Tags: apache-kafka

If single machine contains 4 partitions against same topic. I believe this will be treated as cluster and i need zookeeper to manage the partitions.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zookeeper is always needed for having Apache Kafka working even if you have a single machine with only one Apache Kafka instance.

Comment: Do you Zookeeper is required also for single partition for topic ? It mean Zookeeper is always required whether you have cluster or not ?

Comment: yes it's always required. When you have only one Kafka instance it's just a cluster with a single node. Furthermore, it's independent on how many partitions you have for a topic. Zookeeper is mandatory for having Kafka working.

Comment: Kafka brokers store meta data like Access Control Lists and Topic configuration info in zookeeper so it's required for a single node cluster even though it's not used for distributed consensus or fault tolerance.

Comment: @HansJespersen By Access Control Lists, do you mean security constraints like which partition can be accessed by which consumer ?

Comment: Yes ACLs are security rules and are an example of meta-data that Kafka brokers still store in zookeeper so its still required to have ZK even if you run a single node cluster.